# Customized list of symbols

Tags: lists

I am interested in creating a list of variables or other symbols that I want to be able to customize myself, and therefore I am not interested in packages like glossary or nomenclature. 
I have no idea how to do this other than with a table so I wrote the following piece of code:

```
\newcolumntype{K}[1]{>{\flushleft}m{#1}}
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.1}
\begin{tabular}[t]{ K{12mm} K{3mm} K{120mm} }
$L_f$ & & Monetary value of the damage caused by a hazard (fire, theft...), against which insurance coverage can be taken up. \tabularnewline
$p_f$ & & Probability of occurrence of that hazard.\tabularnewline
$p_d$ & & Probability that the insurer defaults/does not settle its claims.\tabularnewline
$X_0$ & & Position of the initial endowment of the decision-maker.\tabularnewline
$D$ & & Deductible level of a partial insurance contract
\end{tabular}
```

and this is what it yields:
[image]

However, I am struggling to find a way to : vertically allign the text on top (and if possible justify it), reduce the interlign spacing, and interrow spacing. By the way, for some reason:

```
{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.1}
```

does not work for me!

Here's an overview of the outcome I would like to have:

[image]

Thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have to redefine your own column style for this - it is already defined in `tabular` environment as `p{column_width}`. Also if you do not have special reason for defining the column width in milimeters, I would rather use the predefined lengths, such as `\linewidth` or `\textwidth`.

Try the following:

```
\begin{tabular}[t]{p{0.1\linewidth}p{0.9\linewidth} }
  $L_f$ & Monetary value of the damage caused by a hazard (fire, theft...), against which insurance coverage can be taken up. \tabularnewline
  $p_f$ & Probability of occurrence of that hazard.\tabularnewline
  $p_d$ & Probability that the insurer defaults/does not settle its claims.\tabularnewline
  $X_0$ & Position of the initial endowment of the decision-maker.\tabularnewline
  $D$ & Deductible level of a partial insurance contract
\end{tabular}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: thanks, was all simple, i guess i was fooled by latex's complex appearence!

Comment: That will result in overfull boxes as the calculations do not account for the `\tabcolsep` that is added between the columns. So `{@{}p{\dimexpr0.1\linewidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}p{0.9\linewidth}@{}}` will fix that.  This eliminates teh spacing to the left of the first column and the right of the last column and accounts for the `2\tabcolse` between the columns. Also, you need a `\noindent` _before_ `\begin{tabular}`. Alternatively, you can use the `tabularx` package.